# Hibernate global last update (timestamp?)

Tags: hibernate, timestamp

I am looking for a way to find out when the last data-change was made in/by hibernate.
I am looking for this information globally - not for each object/entity/table/column/row.

So the question I want to get answered by hibernate is: When did you last update your data?

Is there a "right"/"hibernate" way or do I have to implement this on my own?

THX!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a listener, configured to listener to appropriate event (post-update, post-delete, post-insert for example). The complete list can be found in the source of `org.hibernate.event.EventListeners`.

Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-events to know how to register your listener(s).

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Hibernate Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers)